# Identifying patterns dynamically:No regex

Tags: java, parsing, pattern-matching

Is there any way in java to identify a sentence format dynamically and find another word/group of words which matched to this format?

for eg :

```
workExperience:
some text

educationalQualification:
some text
```

Assume that worExperience is the first line of a text file. The java program should scan this line and extract the sentence format as `xY` where `x` is a all lowercase word and `Y` is a word with its first letter as caps. Then using this , it should match `educationalQualification` as a match. 
This has to be dynamically as the format may vary from file to file. Ex, the first line of another file maybe `Work Experience`.

For now what we have done is we created a set of possible format templates and try to match them using this. Is there other way to do this ?

Here i am not looking for a text match. i want to identify the format of the fisrt line that is `workExperience` and want to match all other word groups in the file which falls under this format , in this example it should find `educationalQualification`

possible formats may be

```
Work Experience
workExperience
WORK EXPERIENCE
work Experience etc
```

Comment: So you don't want to use regex, why?

Comment: Btw, for pattern matching questions it would be helpful to post a few examples of input and expected output.

Comment: it would be helpful if you described what possible formats you want to support and generally how you wish your algorithm worked on different inputs.

Comment: That still sounds like regex usecase.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care only about combination of lower/uppercase letters and spaces, then you could build a regexp dynamically based on the first line of input. You can make good use of Guava's [CharMatcher](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html).

Something like this:

```
String getPattern(String fromString) {
    Map<CharMatcher, String> charToRegex = Maps.newHashMap();
    charToRegex.put(CharMatcher.JAVA_LOWER_CASE, "[a-z]");
    charToRegex.put(CharMatcher.JAVA_UPPER_CASE, "[A-Z]");
    charToRegex.put(CharMatcher.WHITESPACE, "\\s");

    StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder();
    String lastRegexPart = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < fromString.length(); i++) {
        for (CharMatcher matcher : charToRegex.keySet()) {
            if (matcher.apply(fromString.charAt(i))) {
                String regexPart = charToRegex.get(matcher);
                if (lastRegexPart.equals(regexPart)) {
                    if (pattern.lastIndexOf("+") != pattern.length() - 1) {
                        pattern.append("+");
                    }
                } else {
                    pattern.append(regexPart);
                    lastRegexPart = regexPart;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return pattern.toString();
}
```

Seems to work quite nice:

```
getPattern("workExperience"); // returns [a-z]+[A-Z][a-z]+
getPattern("Work Experience"); // returns [A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+
```

Even if your requirements are somewhat more complicated, I think you could fine-tune this algorithm to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to match any permutation of `work experience:` you could try to make the line lower case and remove all spaces, i.e.

```
"work experience:".toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ","").equals("workexperience:");
"work experience:".toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ","").equals("workexperience:");   
"Work Experience:".toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ","").equals("workexperience:");   
"workExperience:".toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ","").equals("workexperience:");   
"workexperience:".toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ","").equals("workexperience:");   
" work   experience   :".toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ","").equals("workexperience:");
```

Those would all return true.

Alternatively, use `equalsIgnoreCase()`:

```
"work experience:".replaceAll(" ","").equalsIgnoreCase( "workexperience:");
```

Edit: switching the arguments would make it more readable:

```
"workexperience:".equalsIgnoreCase( "work experience:".replaceAll(" ",""));
"workexperience:".equalsIgnoreCase( "workExperience:".replaceAll(" ",""));
"workexperience:".equalsIgnoreCase( "Work Experience:".replaceAll(" ",""));
"workexperience:".equalsIgnoreCase( "WorkExperience:".replaceAll(" ",""));
"workexperience:".equalsIgnoreCase( "   work experience    :".replaceAll(" ",""));
```